# JQuery - Treeview with context menu(Add, Edit, Delete)

Tags: jquery

I am new to Jquery, below given task needs to be done using jquery(Both Treeview and context menu). I would be thankful for some one who can suggest the answer. Thanks in advance

I want to display Jquery TreeView and bind a context menu to it. ContextMenu should contain options like (Add, Edit, Delete), the TreeView contains a tree structure as follows

```
Parent1
    Child1
           Child1.1
                   Child1.1.1( After this node I should restrict addtion of further
                               childs)
    Child2
           Child2.1
                   Child2.1.1( Same as above)
Parent2
     (Same as above)
```

So from Node 1 I should be able to add the child nodes or delete the nodes or edit the nodes, While deleting I should get an alert message, while editing I should be able to edit the text for the child controls with double click option or rename option.

Comment: What have you tried? Stack Overflow is not a place to get people to write code for you.

Comment: Here is the Div I used to populate context menu
<div id="tree1"></div>
    <div id="Menu">
        <div id="add" style="background-color: lightgray; width: 200px">Add</div>
        <div id="remove" style="background-color: Gray; width: 200px">Remove</div>
        <div id="update" style="background-color: lightgray; width: 200px">Update</div>
    </div>
    <input id="updateText" type="text" /><br />

Answer (score 0):

To create jquery tree with context menu follow [this great tutorial series](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-tree-with-context-menu/).

Answer (score 0):

I use [jstree](http://www.jstree.com/) plugin.
On this site you can find demos and documentation. First try it, and if you have a troubles, ask community there.

Answer (score 0):

you have 3 greate options:
1- [`Fancytree`](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-jQuery-UI-Dynamic-Tree-View-Plugin-Fancytree/demo/)
2- [`easy-tree`](https://github.com/zgs225/easy-tree)
3- [`jsTree`](https://www.jstree.com/)

[Fancytree](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-jQuery-UI-Dynamic-Tree-View-Plugin-Fancytree/demo/) is a complete tool, but if you need more graphic tools you have to use [Treed](https://jquery-plugins.net/treed-powerful-tree-editor).